# can't seem to access uefi bios on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop, uefi

I have an HP desktop and got windows 10 through the free upgrade promotion, but unfortunately I can't run my new evga GTX 750 TI SC. I heard it my be due to the bios but I've looked everywhere and nothing seems to get me to them. My Desktop is a HP Pavillion HPE h8-1125. And I have the fast boot option off too

Comment: I upgraded from Win 7, just talked to a computer place told me all I had to do was d/l the drivers from where I bought the card before putting it in. Going to see if that works. Oh, and did the whole shift thing, still didn't come up as an option, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access BIOS/UEFI by following these steps:

1. Open Start menu and click "Power".
2. Hold down SHIFT and click "Restart". Instead of rebooting, Windows should
   show blue boot options menu.
3. From there go to **Troubleshoot --> Advanced options --> UEFI firmaware settings.**
4. Press "Restart".

Now Windows should boot to BIOS/UEFI.

You can also try to go to  **Windows settings --> Update & security --> Recovery** and from there under the "Advanced startup" select "Restart now". That should take you to the same boot options menu mentioned earlier.

If you haven't already, you should also download nVidia GeForce Experience from http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience. It will help you to keep your video drivers up to date. It also has other handy features like screen recording and FPS counter.